# Deep link with optional query parameters

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation, android-deep-link

**Edit:** This is a bug (missing feature?) in the manifest merger. It works in Android Studio 3.5 Canary 5 and above. So what one want's to do is to add one `<deepLink />` per uri. Which in my case would be

```
<deepLink
    android:id="@+id/deepLink"
    app:uri="https://www.example.com/foo?cn={cardNumber}&amp;bd={birthDate}"/>

<deepLink
    android:id="@+id/deepLink2"
    app:uri="https://www.example.com/foo?cn={cardNumber}"/>
```

---

I have a deep link in the form `"https://www.example.com/foo?cn=L349DA&bd=1982-03-12"`

and I parse it in my navigation graph with

```
<deepLink
    android:id="@+id/deepLink"
    app:uri="https://www.example.com/foo?cn={cardNumber}&amp;bd={birthDate}"/>
```

That all works well. But my parameter `bd` is optional, so I'm not guaranteed that it will be included in the url. How do we handle this case?

I've tried with wildcards `*` on the parameter with no luck. And I've tried with adding two `<deepLink .../>` elements, but that yields a `Manifest merger failed: Multiple destinations...` error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know this is a few months old but... keep the bd={birthDate} in there and make the param nullable.  just null check for it in the fragment.  Would that not work for you?

Comment: @Psest328 as said in the edit at the top of the post, this bug is fixed since AS 3.5 Canary 5.

Answer (score 1):

In "**androidx.navigation:navigation-*:2.2.0-alpha02**"

September 5, 2019

Deep links with query parameters now support reordered query parameters; arguments that have a default value or are nullable are now optional when matching deep links. ([b/133273839](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133273839))

[Android Developers Jetpack AndroidX Navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation)